# Prove that every monotone function is a.e differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that every monotone function is a.e differentiable

**My attempt:**

Let $f$ a monotone function in $[a,b]$. As $f$ is monotone then $f$ is bounded variation function in $[a,b]$

Moreover, we know that if $f$ is bounded variation then $f$ is continuous except at countably many point.

Then, $f$ is differentiable except in a countable many points and we know that the measure of a countable many sets is zero, In consequence $f$ is a.e differentiable

Is correct this?

Comment: It is not clear how you deduce from " $f$ is continuous except at countably many point " that "$f$ is differentiable except in a countable many points "

Comment: This happen because $f$ is monotone and a.e continous @DiegoG7

Comment: But if you say so, you have to prove that: "if $f(x)$ is monotone and $f$ is continuous in $x_0$, then $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$". I do not wether that   is true (at least one should admit that $f'(x_0)=+\infty $ is included in the definition of differentiable)

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ has bounded variation in $[0,1]$ but infinite derivative at a point. So I think that your proof is not complete: you need to justify why the function has finite derivative at almost all continuity points.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function this function is differentiable almost everywhere and is monotone and continuous, but fails to have a derivative at uncountably many points.